# R and osmar : the doc's example does not work for me, "Opening and ending tag mismatch"

Tags: openstreetmap, r, documentation

I can't make osmar work anymore. I tried to reproduce the documentation's example, and even that produces a very long error code. I could not find the same error anywhere. Any idea ?

The code is :

```
require(osmar)  
api <- osmsource_api()  
box <- corner_bbox(11.579341, 48.15102, 11.582852, 48.1530)  
gschw <- get_osm(box, source = api)
```

The error is :

> Opening and ending tag mismatch: BR line 6 and FONT
>   AttValue: " or ' expected
>   attributes construct error
>   Couldn't find end of Start Tag TABLE line 9
>   AttValue: " or ' expected
>   attributes construct error
>   Couldn't find end of Start Tag FONT line 11
>   Opening and ending tag mismatch: BR line 14 and FONT
>   Opening and ending tag mismatch: BR line 13 and TD
>   Opening and ending tag mismatch: TD line 10 and TR
>   AttValue: " or ' expected
>   attributes construct error
>   Couldn't find end of Start Tag HR line 19
>   AttValue: " or ' expected
>   attributes construct error
>   Couldn't find end of Start Tag HR line 24
>   Opening and ending tag mismatch: BR line 23 and FONT
>   Opening and ending tag mismatch: BR line 22 and TD
>   Opening and ending tag mismatch: BR line 20 and TR
>   AttValue: " or ' expected
>   attributes construct error
>   Couldn't find end of Start Tag FONT line 34
>   EntityRef: expecting ';'
>   Opening and ending tag mismatch: br line 36 and FONT
>   Opening and ending tag mismatch: br line 36 and i
>   Opening and ending tag mismatch: br line 36 and B
>   Opening and ending tag mismatch: BR line 35 and TD
>   Opening and ending tag mismatch: B line 33 and TR
>   Opening and ending tag mismatch: i line 33 and TABLE
>   Opening and ending tag mismatch: TD line 32 and blockquote
>   Opening and ending tag mismatch: TR line 32 and FONT
>   Opening and ending tag mismatch: FONT line 18 and BODY
>   Opening and ending tag mismatch: TD line 17 and HTML
>   Premature end of data in tag TR line 17
>   Premature end of data in tag TR line 10
>   Premature end of data in tag blockquote line 8
>   Premature end of data in tag FONT line 5
>   Premature end of data in tag BODY line 4
>   Premature end of data in tag HTML line 1
>   Error: 1: Opening and ending tag mismatch: BR line 6 and FONT
>   2: AttValue: " or ' expected
>   3: attributes construct error
>   4: Couldn't find end of Start Tag TABLE line 9
>   5: AttValue: " or ' expected
>   6: attributes construct error
>   7: Couldn't find end of Start Tag FONT line 11
>   8: Opening and ending tag mismatch: BR line 14 and FONT
>   9: Opening and ending tag mismatch: BR line 13 and TD
>   10: Opening and ending tag mismatch: TD line 10 and TR
>   11: AttValue: " or ' expected
>   12: attributes construct error
>   13: Couldn't find end of Start Tag HR line 19
>   14: AttValue: " or ' expected
>   15: attributes construct error
>   16: Couldn't find end of Start Tag HR line 24
>   17: Opening and ending tag mismatch: BR line 23 and FONT
>   18: Opening and ending tag mismatch: BR line 22 and TD
>   19: Opening and ending tag mismatch: BR line 20 and TR
>   20: AttValue: " or ' expected
>   21: attributes construct error
>   22: Couldn't find end of Start Tag FONT line 34
>   23: EntityRef: expecting ';'
>   24: Opening and ending tag mismatch: br l

Comment: The example works for me, it seems that `get_osm_data` fetched a HTML page instead of OSM XML data in your error. Check the output of `osmar:::get_osm_data.api(api, box)`, this should be in OSM XML format.

Comment: Thank you Rainer Stuetz. I'm behind a proxy, which may be transforming an HTML error into an HTML page like "hi dude, I can't help you". Then this page may be parsed as OSM XML without much success. I will have a look at it :)

Comment: Just tried `osmar:::get_osm_data.api(api, box)`, and it indeed is a bunch of html telling me I should fill in my credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP here, I can now answer my own question thanks to Rainer Stuetz :)

The call was made from behind a proxy, and without proper login / password. Therefore, the proxy returned an HTTP page instead of an XML one, which in turn could not be parsed as XML (obviously).

You can diagnose the problem with a call to `osmar:::get_osm_data.api(api, box)`. If it does **not** return XML, then we have the same issue.

I'm currently trying to know how to set the login/pass [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198292/how-to-use-osmar-behind-a-proxy).